# Prove with pumping lemma that the language { $a^n b^n b^m a^m | n ≠ m $ } is not context free

Tags: context-free, pumping-lemma

I'm having a trouble proving it to be non-context-free.

For example, if I take w = $a^k b^k b^{k+1} a^{k+1}$, it would be problematic if the partition of $vxy$ with $|v| = |y|$ was in the $ b^{k+1} a^{k+1} $ part as I can't get it to be equal with $k$ or make the amount of $a$s and $b$s different.

We are also allowed to use Ogden's Lemma.

Comment: Are you familiar with the pumping lemma proof that $\{a^nb^m \mid n \neq m\}$ isn't regular?

Comment: The trick is explained here: [Prove that the following language is not regular: $\{ 0^i1^j \mid i\neq j \}$](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/116394/4287).

Comment: Consider $ab b^{p!+1} a^{p!+1}$. If $n,m$ can be zero, we can also consider $b^{p!} a^{p!}$. Here $p$ is a pumping length.